# SubSonic 3 vs SubSonic 2: Generating Code flexibility?

Tags: vb.net, subsonic3

How can I reach the same flexibility with generated classes in SubSonic 3 as I had in SubSonic 2?

Main needs:

- select which tables include or exclude
- generated files Target

Comment: I found how can i exclude tables:
In the Sittings template there is a list named "ExcludeTables"
u can fill it with excluded tables names

I think its easy to add an included tabl list and use it in the same places that "ExcludeTables" is used.

Comment: So did you find the answer to all of your questions?

Comment: Yes i had for this question but i had post other questionthat no body answerd yet and i cant progress with out resolving them.
Question Name: "SubSonic3 VB.Net Add,Update, FirstOrDefault Problems" Question Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372275/subsonic3-vb-net-add-update-firstordefault-problems