# SubSonic3 VB.Net Add,Update, FirstOrDefault Problems

Tags: vb.net, activerecord, subsonic3

I hade build sctive record dal with subsonic3 Vb.net templates. and i am dealing with alot of bugs in the sub sonic dlls.

1)in Add() function: (i have fix)
when indx has counter in the db the returnd new key type is decimal the active record fil have an exception "Public member 'Change Type To' n type 'Decimal' not found". 
i managed to fix this bug. i changed in the activeRecord template the sub

OlD

```
    Public Sub SetKeyValue(value As Object) Implements IActiveRecord.SetKeyValue
        If value IsNot Nothing AndAlso value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
            Dim settable = value.ChangeTypeTo(Of <#=tbl.PK.SysType#>)()
            Me.GetType.GetProperty(Me.KeyName()).SetValue(Me, settable, Nothing)
        End If
    End Sub
```

NEW

```
   Public Sub SetKeyValue(value As Object) Implements IActiveRecord.SetKeyValue
        If value IsNot Nothing AndAlso value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
            Dim settable = CType( value, <#=tbl.PK.SysType#>)
            Me.GetType.GetProperty(Me.KeyName()).SetValue(Me, settable, Nothing)
        End If
    End Sub
```

2)in Update function() function:(I Have Fixed)
  the update never do the work . after debuging it apeard that the sql statment of the update never have the "SET" dection of the query its always Like:
          UPDATE [tableName] WHERE ...
 It seems there  is a problem in the Subsonic.Repository dll -- > IRepository  The
 Dirty     Colums not apdated in new object for example :

1. Dim Cat as db.Category
2. Cat.Indx=1
3. Cat.SetIsNew(False)
4. Cat.Name= 'Motors'
5. Cat.Update

Why when update there is no DirtyColumns How can i set Column as Dirty?

--Update problem resolved its not a bug.-- 
Resolved by adding after line 3 : CAT.SetIsLoaded(True) .
So when the propety IsLoaded is set to tru any column updated will be added to DirtyColums and thes will be Updated To DB

3) the FirstOrDefault Function : (Couldn't fix)
always i meaaaaaaaaan always throw exsiption = "Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '('."
from the SubSonic.Linq dll

Pleeeeeeeeeeeease help

Thanks In advance,
TheGodfather

Comment: There's really too many questions here. I would suggest you split this one question into three separate questions to make it easier for others to help/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firtly, which version of SubSonic3 are you using?

1) Not sure what you are trying to do here.

2) That is not how you update a record, try this...

```
Dim cat = Category.SingleOrDefault(Function(item) item.CategoryID = 1)
cat.CategoryName = "MOTORS"
cat.Update()
```

3) Subsonic uses `SingleOrDefault()` as example above demonstrates.

Comment: MAIN PROBLEM :
I am using SubSonic 3 With sqlServer 2000.

 the FirstOrDefault Function :  always i meaaaaaaaaan always throw exsiption = "Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '('." from the SubSonic.Linq dll

Comment: Okay. But as I said, maybe you should be using SingleOrDefault()? My example above (2) works for me, I am not sure why it wouldn't for you.

Comment: Or perhaps the following works... cat = Category.Find(Function(item) item.CategoryID = 1).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Thanks for your time .
did you try it with sql server 2000.
i think that this is the problem somthing with hidden query sentax .
in each select query subsonic3 add "TOP (n)" after the "SELECT",and this sentax is worng in sqlserver 2000 its should be " TOP n".
so Know I am 99.999% sure that this a bug.